# radcharview has lost all colors after theming

Tags: c#, telerik

I've set theme office2007Black for my application like this

```
private void MainWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ThemeResolutionService.ApplicationThemeName = "Office2007Black";
}
```

But after this my radchartview in another form of this app has lost all color(line series has become all grey). I've set `this.radChartView1.EnableTheming = false;` but it didn't help. How to return(or set) colors for lines without theme deleting?

Comment: did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Instead, try something like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : RadRibbonWindow
{
    static MainWindow()
    {
        RadRibbonWindow.IsWindowsThemeEnabled = false;
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        StyleManager.ApplicationTheme = new Office_BlackTheme();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

refer to this doc: [RadWindow](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/radribbonview-ribbon-window-wpf.html)